# How to connect to SQL database with react?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, reactjs

I currently have a website, written in HTML and PHP, that can access my SQL database. I have now started learning React and want my super simple website to also connect to an SQL database.

Previously i've done this:

```
<php
    $conn = mysqli_connect($serverIP, $dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
    if(mysqli_errno($conn)) {
     die("<p>MySQL error:</p>\n<p>" . mysqli_error($conn) . "</p>\n</body>\n</html>\n");
    }
?>
```

and then in the index.php file, done this:

```
<?php include_once "connection.php"; ?>
```

And continued with basic SQL to fetch data.

How do I do the same in React? More specifically, how do I write PHP in React to be able to connect to an SQL database? How does this code look like?

Also, as I am learning React on my own it would be great if there was a place where people could review code, and where I could receive tips on improvement. Is there such a website/community?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you may not understand how to layers quite fit together yet (don't worry - it takes some time to wrap your head around). In your case, your server-side (PHP) code will make all of your database calls and retrieve / modify any data you need (you don't want to have your database credentials viewable on the client-side, after all!).

In order to display or change data from your React JS front-end, you'll need a way to communicate these intentions to the backend; this can be done by creating REST endpoints in your PHP codebase, which you will then need to call from your React JS code (you can use Axios, fetch or many other HTTP libraries for this).

Here's a super simple example that I grabbed from /u/roboctocat on reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8lb6u3/can_anyone_provide_me_a_basic_example_tutorial/

Your client code:

```
// index.jsx
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    onClick() { 
        fetch("http://your-php-server/ping-pong.php")
            .then(res => res.json()) 
            .then((result) => { console.log(result); }) 
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <button onClick={this.onClick} /> 
        ); 
    } 
}
```

And your server code:

```
// ping-pong.php
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
    echo json_encode(array('ping' => 'pong')); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const getData()=>{
  //function to fetch data
  const handleData=()=>{
    axios.get('php file path')
      .then(response=>response.json())
      .then((data)=>console.log(data.json));{

    }
  }

  return(
  <>
      <button onClick={handleData}></button>
  </>
  );
} //end main

export default getData()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest you to write your php code as below:

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect($serverIP, $dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
    if(mysqli_errno($conn)) {
     
     $connError = array(
         "status" => boolval(0),
         "error" => mysqli_errno($conn)
     );

     $error = json_encode($connError);

     die($error);
    }
```

Now you get much better response to handle in React from your backend.

Then in next step you can call fetch api to send request to your backend and check the database connection:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://your-server/connection.php")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => console.log(res));
}, []);
```

Now with `useEffect()` hook you can check the database connection once on each page load.

Also you can check if `typeof` for `res` is `array` then do something like showing error message to user.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to commercial alternatives, lolaDB is a great option to connect to most major databases without any backend/API code.

```js
const data = await loladb.query.execute({
  queryId = "get-all-recent-orders"
})

// data = [{ "orderId" : 123, .... }]
```